# Sub-licensing an "Open Data Commons Attribution License (ODC-By) v1.0" Database

Tags: api, uses-of-open-data

I have my own database that I would like to combine with another database for redundancy. The other database is released under the "[Open Data Commons Attribution License (ODC-By) v1.0](https://opendatacommons.org/licenses/by/1.0/)"

Can I license my combined database under this same license?